# Contar quantos campos vazios tem no formulário com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho os seguintes campos vindos do banco de dados:

```
<?php 
while($peListar = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlListar){
    .....
    $listar .= "<td style='".$fundo."'><input type='text' name='ValorI[]'  class='md-form-control'  value=''></td>";
    $listar .= "<td style='".$fundo."'><input type='text' name='ValorII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>";
    $listar .= "<td style='".$fundo."'><input type='text' name='ValorIII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>";
    $listar .= "<td style='".$fundo."'><input type='text' name='ValorFinal[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>";
    .....
}
?>
```

Porém gostaria de contar quantos campos vazios tem, ou seja, quantos campos não foram digitados pelo usuário. Entende-se que não quero uma validação de campos ;) , mas apenas contar o total de quantos campos que não foram preenchidos. Tentei usar o código abaixo, mas não funcionou:

```
....
$(\"[name^='ValorI']\").on(\"input\", function(){
.....
var myForm = this.form;
var vazios = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < myForm.elements.length; i++) {
if (myForm.elements[i].value === \"\")
 vazios += 1;
}
alert(vazios);
....
```

Comment: Inclusive o "valorFinal"?

Comment: Olá dvd. Sem o valorFinal. Na verdade é em cima da sua solução que você me passou no post antigo. Como é um outro assunto, abri esse post. `Seria nessa linha: $("[name='ValorFinal[]']", parent).val((valor1+valor2)/3);` onde o valor `3`, seria o valor dos campos preenchidos, ignorando os campos vazios, ou seja, se prencher apenas 02 campos, ficaria `2`.

Comment: Ah sim, eu postei a resposta contando todos os campos da tabela... mas vc quer apenas da linha, não é mesmo?

Comment: Editei a resposta. No seu caso seria "contar campos preenchidos" e não "vazios"... neste caso é só retirar o `!` de `!$(this).val();`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso com `filter`. Irá retornar apenas o número de campos vazios na linha:

```js
$("[name^='ValorI']").on("input", function(){

   var linha = $(this).closest("tr"); // seleciona a linha TR
   
   // busca os inputs na linha com name iniciando com "ValorI"
   var campos = $("[name^='ValorI']", linha);

   // conta apenas os vazios
   var vazios = campos.filter(function(){
       return !$(this).val();
   }).length;

   console.log(vazios);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorI[]'  class='md-form-control'  value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorIII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorFinal[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorI[]'  class='md-form-control'  value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorIII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorFinal[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorI[]'  class='md-form-control'  value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorIII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorFinal[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos, mas a resposta do dvd serviu melhor para a minha dúvida.

Comment: afinal de contas, contar o que mesmo? :D até agora não consegui saber ao certo

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Os campos vazios em cada linha. :D

Answer (score 1):

De uma forma mais direta, bastando preencher os inputs, a função vai contar quantos estão nulos.

Quando você usa `name^='ValorI'` está excluindo da contagem o ultimo `input` de cada linha.

```js
$("[name^='ValorI']").on("input", function(){
var matches = 0;

    $("[name^='ValorI']").each(function(i, val) {
       if ($(this).val() == '') {
          matches++;
       }
    });

console.log(matches);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorI[]'  class='md-form-control'  value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorIII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorFinal[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorI[]'  class='md-form-control'  value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorIII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorFinal[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorI[]'  class='md-form-control'  value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorIII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorFinal[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
   </tr>
   
</table>
```